# Why is .card-header not rendering properly in my React Bootstrap setup?

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

My current frontend is set up with React, TypeScript, Webpack, Sass and React Bootstrap. I followed the [React Bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#installation) and installed the dependencies.

```json
"bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
```

Then I added an import to include the stylesheet like so (with Sass):

```
// CSS reset
@import '@scss/reset.scss';
// Override the bootstrap SCSS (completely empty for now)
@import '@scss/custom.scss';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then I import the .scss file into my App.tsx file:

```
import './App.scss';
```

Everything seems to work fine, except the .card-header class does not. It should fill up the rounded corners as shown in the [Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/).

[image]

The code responsible for the picture above is copied from the Bootstrap example.

```html
<div className="card">
    <div className="card-header">Featured</div>
    <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p className="card-text">
            With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
        </p>
        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
            Go somewhere
        </a>
    </div>
</div>;
```

I have most likely forgotten some step in the installation process, but I just do not know what.

Comment: Your card class seems to have a padding all around. My advice will be to inspect the element in the browser, and see which line of code the padding is coming from. If it's coming from default Bootstrap, then you could add some `p-0` classes, or if its coming from somewhere else, you could edit those out.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Row component from React Bootstrap passed some CSS to its children that contains padding-left and padding-right statements.

```css
.row > * {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
```

This caused the problem that I had with the card header. I fixed this by adding p-0 to my card div.

**EDIT: I completely overlooked the fact that React Bootstrap has a built-in Card component...**

Comment: You should accept your own answer as the solution answer so other users can easily see it!

Comment: Agreed, but it says that I have to wait until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your whole code but seems like some other css, maybe something from custom.css is interfering with the bootstrap styling.

Comment: custom.css is currently completely empty, so that cannot be the case. reset.scss does not seem to be a problem either.

Comment: Please generate a jsfiddle and share your code.